# C# Naudio - Ear Blasting sound recorded from default devices (Microphone & Playback)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, naudio

Hi I am looking to record sound coming from default recording device (current microphone) and the sound coming from the desktop (default playback device) into one file. However all I get is a very loud sound of ear blasting nothing. What am I doing wrong? My devices are working fine, I have a sound card so maybe that's part of the problem working with NAudio.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder();

                while (true)
                {
                    recorder.StartRecording();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public WaveInEvent microphoneInput;
        public WasapiLoopbackCapture systemSoundInput;
        public WaveFileWriter writer;
        public string outputPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        public int fileIndex = 0;

        public AudioRecorder()
        {
            // microphone input
            microphoneInput = new WaveInEvent();
            // system sound input
            systemSoundInput = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

            // event handlers for data available
            microphoneInput.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
            systemSoundInput.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
        }

        public void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            writer?.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

        public void StartRecording()
        {
            string fileName = $"recording_{fileIndex++}.wav";
            writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputPath + fileName, microphoneInput.WaveFormat);

            microphoneInput.StartRecording();
            systemSoundInput.StartRecording();

            // Record for 5 seconds
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            StopRecording();
        }

        public void StopRecording()
        {
            microphoneInput.StopRecording();
            systemSoundInput.StopRecording();
            writer?.Dispose();
            writer = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are capturing from two different devices that are using different audio formats and writing it all to one WAV file. That simply won't work and is why you are hearing noise. You need to convert the audio to a common format and mix it together.

The easiest option would be to have separate `WaveFileWriter` instances for the microphone and the system audio, and create a WAV file for each.

The system audio will be stereo 32 bit IEEE float format, and the microphone will likely be mono 16 bit PCM samples. So you'd need to use the other utility classes in NAudio to get them to a common format in order to mix them.